# raphael js pie chart move slices

Tags: javascript, charts, svg, raphael

I would want to move the slices of a pie using raphael, in this manner
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/demo/monthly-sales-moveslice.html . I know how to scale the slices with the center point fixed, but i am trying to move the slice not scale it. Thank you

Comment: Did you check the raphaël examples? http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html does exactly that.

Comment: Hi Erik.. Sorry if my question was not clear.. That is scaling, which i am aware of. What i wanted is to move the sector in the direction it is from the origin on hover. Please look at the link i provided. I have seen not just the examples but also read through the reference of raphael but am still not sure of how to achieve it.

Comment: you should edit the question to make it clearer